# Adding custom header in HTTP request of prometheus

Tags: prometheus

Prometheus send HTTP request to get monitor values. My custom export supports variety of clients (to monitors system status). There is a general REST API to get list of monitors:

```
/api/v1/monitor/find
```

the output result depend on Accept attribute in header. The default accept value is application/json.

I add new mime type to support prometheus (e.g. application/prometheus) into the API.

But, how to config Prometheus to add a custom header (Accept: application/prometheus)?

Comment: I know, it is possible to set param. But I`m looking for header.

Comment: maybe see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66032498/prometheus-scrape-metric-with-custom-header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it is not support in current version (V2.0 alpha).

If you take a look at the [scrapes.go](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/fa6e05903fd3ce52e374a6e1bf4eb98c9f1f45a7/scrape/scrape.go#L788-L792) in the master branch, then you can see some constant header attached into request:

```go
req.Header.Add("Accept", acceptHeader)
req.Header.Set("User-Agent", userAgentHeader)
req.Header.Set("X-Prometheus-Scrape-Timeout-Seconds", fmt.Sprintf("%f", s.timeout.Seconds()))
```

So, there are some basic mime-types which you can support:

```
application/vnd.google.protobuf;proto=io.prometheus.client.MetricFamily;encoding=delimited;q=0.7,text/plain;version=0.0.4;q=0.3,*/*;q=0.1
```

None of artifacts on premetheus.io added this header, so you have to build from source (master branch).

I run a PHP exporter (my own exporter), here is screen shot of request header

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus doesn't support setting headers, as that would lead to users creating hard to debug endpoints. You can either use a separate endpoint or pass a parameter.

Prometheus also already has a specified mime type for scrapes, so you could use that. See https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats/