# Prometheus scrape /metric with custom header

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I have an application that will be monitored by Prometheus,
but the application need the custom header key like :

```
x-auth-token: <customrandomtoken>
```

What should I do with prometheus.yml?

Comment: Hi Ronaldo, check this Prometheus Documentation link: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#scrape_config

Maybe the 'bearer_token' or http 'params' parameters it's what you need.
```yaml
# Optional HTTP URL parameters.
params:
  [ <string>: [<string>, ...] ]

# Sets the `Authorization` header on every scrape request with
# the configured bearer token. It is mutually exclusive with `bearer_token_file`.
[ bearer_token: <secret> ]
```

Comment: i need custom header like 
```
x-api-token: <mygeneratedcustomtoken>
```

Comment: Then try using 'params:' to add a HTTP header

Comment: params is for "Optional HTTP URL parameters", it's definitely not a header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prometheus itself does not have a way to define custom headers in order to reach an exporter. The idea of adding the feature was discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/1724). Tl;dr: if you need a custom header, inject it with a forward proxy (I posted an example in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74268939/11344502)).

The `prometheus-blackbox-exporter` tag suggest that the question is about the exporter that makes probes, which is a separate thing and it does have a way to set headers. Only, ***it does not scrape metrics, it makes them***.

Blackbox exporter has it's own configuration file and it consists of *modules*. A module is a set of parameters, defining how to do the probe and what result to expect. Here is an example of a module that looks for 200-299 response code and uses  `X-Auth-Token` header:

```yaml
modules:
  http_2xx_with_header:
    prober: http
    http:
      headers:
        X-Auth-Token: skdjfh98732hjf22exampletoken
```

More examples can be found [here](https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter/blob/master/example.yml) and the list of configuration options - [here](https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md).

When you made the blackbox exporter to load the new configuration, you need to adjust Prometheus configuration as well:

```yaml
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'blackbox'
    metrics_path: /probe
    params:
      module: [http_2xx_with_header]  # <- Here goes the name of the new module
    static_configs:
      - targets:
        - http://prometheus.io
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        target_label: __param_target
      - source_labels: [__param_target]
        target_label: instance
      - target_label: __address__
        replacement: 127.0.0.1:9115
```

Answer (score 2):

Prometheus doesn't support specifying custom HTTP headers, which must be sent with each scrape request to scrape target :( However, it supports specifying `Authorization` header via `authorization` and `basic_auth` options at [scrape_config](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#scrape_config) section.

For example, the following config instructs Prometheus to send `Authorization: My-Auth my-super-secret` header with each scrape request to `http://localhost:8428/metrics`:

```yaml
scrape_configs:
- job_name: foo
  authorization:
    type: "My-Auth"
    credentials: "my-super-secret"
  static_configs:
  - targets: ["localhost:8428"]
```

P.S. If you still need sending custom http headers with each request to remote target, then take a look at [vmagent](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/vmagent.html) - monitoring agent, which understands Prometheus scrape configs and can scrape Prometheus targets. This is a project I work on. It provides additional features on top of standard `scrape_configs` from Prometheus, including `headers` option - see [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/vmagent.html#how-to-collect-metrics-in-prometheus-format). The `headers` option allows specifying arbitrary number of additional http headers, which need to be sent to scrape target. For example, the following config instructs sending `x-auth-token: <customrandomtoken>` http header with each request to `http://foobar:1234`:

```yaml
scrape_configs:
- job_name: foo
  headers:
  - "x-auth-token: <customrandomtoken>"
  static_configs:
  - targets: ["foobar:1234"]
```